# Salt Water Experiment

Tags: density

If my students pour colored water with differing levels of salinity into a clear container will the colors mix or will the water separate into different levels of salinity?

THANKS!

Comment: It's an easy experiment to try at home.  Your pouring method will make a big difference, so you should work out the technique before you ask your students to do it.

Comment: If you slowly spin the glass, then it really won't mix.

Answer (score 2):

Diffusion in liquids is very slow, so if you can create two layers of differently coloured water they will remain separate layers for many hours. This would be true even with two samples of just water with different colour dyes, but it is exceedingly difficult to prepare two separate layers of just water because they mix with each other so easily.

The advantage of using saline and water is the density difference. If you pour the saline first then gently pour the water on top the less dense water tends to stay as a separate layer on top even if (like me!) you're a bit clumsy when it comes to these delicate experiments.

You are suggesting using saline of different concentrations, and this will also work except that the density differences will be smaller so you will have to be more careful.